# Payment Gate way for Marketplace Application

Tags: paypal, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, braintree

We are developed a marketplace application , that helps shops to sell their products globally.Now we are checking a best payment gateway that supports all countries.I checked some of the well know gateways but all of them have merchat country restriction.In our application any shops (from anywhere in the world)can sell their products through the platform.
Which is best payment gateway that has a global merchat support?

Answer (score -1):

The gateway you are looking for does not exist. There is no reputable gateway that can or will allow any seller anywhere in the world to sell to any buyer. That's not how the law works.